# summary of median values in a 3x3 table in R

Tags: r, median, summary

Taking some generic data

```
set.seed(123)
A <- sample(1997:2000, 50, replace=TRUE)
B <- sample(1:3, 50, replace=TRUE)
C <- rnorm(50)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I want to create a summary table that for each `A` value (year), and then each `B` value (type), will print the corresponding median `C` value

I have tried the following code

in reference to [this](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html) website

```
mytable <- table(df$A, df$B, median(df$C))
ftable(mytable)
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852408/frequency-table-with-several-variables-in-r)

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(A), summarize,
      type=unique(B),
      median=median(C))
```

but neither seems to work. The desired output should look similar to this:
[image]

Comment: `ddply(df, .(A, B), summarize, median=median(C))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .(median = median(C)), by = c("A", "B")][order(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `dplyr` would be :

```
df %>%
    group_by(A,B)%>%
    summarise(C = median(C))
```

Read above code like :
1st group by A and B, then summarise C by median of each group.